# How can I count rows of a Table in a Word document with C#

Tags: c#, count, ms-word, row

I want to know how to open a Word Document that contains a table and count how many rows it contains.

I investigated these two days, but I had no luck.. so I was not able to even start the code.. I’d appreciate any help.

Comment: what have you tried.

Comment: Should probably let people know what you have investigated so far.

If you haven't got very far, the Microsoft Office COM API is probably a good place to start: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.table?view=word-pia

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is the Visual Studio 2022 .NET Core demo.

If you have MS Word installed, first refer to the COM reference:

[image]
[image]

```cs
using StackOverflowCSConsoleApp1;
using winword=Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

MyClass.How_can_I_count_rows_of_a_Table_in_a_Word_document_with_CSharpHow_can_I_count_rows_of_a_Table_in_a_Word_document_with_CSharp();

namespace StackOverflowCSConsoleApp1 {

    public static class MyClass
    {
        
        public static void How_can_I_count_rows_of_a_Table_in_a_Word_document_with_CSharpHow_can_I_count_rows_of_a_Table_in_a_Word_document_with_CSharp()
        {
            //winword.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
            winword.Application app = new winword.Application();
            const string filename = @"A:\Users\oscar\Dropbox\VS\VBA\stackoverflow.docm";
            winword.Documents docs=app.Documents;
            winword.Document doc=docs.Open(filename);
            if (doc.Tables.Count > 0)
            {
                int rowsCount = 0;
                try
                {
                    rowsCount= doc.Tables[1].Rows.Count;

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    switch (ex.HResult)
                    {
                        default:
                            Console.WriteLine(ex.HResult + ex.Message);
                            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
                            break;
                    }
                }

                Console.WriteLine("the " + Path.GetFileName( filename) + " table1's rows count is " + rowsCount);

            }
            app.Quit();
        }

    }

}
```